# javascript loop through fields, add values and display on another field

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which loops through a number of fields, which their ID prefix and suffix is the same, see code below.
I am stuck trying to add the total values of all related fields and displaying it on textbox Id txtTOTAL20, txtTOTAL40 and txtTOTAL50.
This is what I have so far (which doesn't work)

```
for (var i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    x = i + 1
    var field1 = "txtF" + i + "_1"; 
    var field2 = "txtF" + i + "_2"; 
    var field3 = "txtF" + i + "_3"
    FIELD20 = FIELD20 + parseInt(field1.value);
    FIELD40 = FIELD40 + parseInt(field2.value);
    FIELD50 = FIELD50 + parseInt(field3.value);
    var text = document.getElementById('txtTOTAL20');text.value = FIELD20;
    var text = document.getElementById('txtTOTAL40');text.value = FIELD40;
    var text = document.getElementById('txtTOTAL50');text.value = FIELD50;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
//init
var FIELD20 = 0;
var FIELD40 = 0;
var FIELD50 = 0;

for (var i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    //get values
    var field1 = document.getElementById("txtF" + i + "_1"); 
    var field2 = document.getElementById("txtF" + i + "_2"); 
    var field3 = document.getElementById("txtF" + i + "_3");

    //increment
    FIELD20 += parseInt(field1.value);
    FIELD40 += parseInt(field2.value);
    FIELD50 += parseInt(field3.value);
}

//display totals
document.getElementById('txtTOTAL20').value = FIELD20;
document.getElementById('txtTOTAL40').value = FIELD40;
document.getElementById('txtTOTAL50').value = FIELD50;
```

Comment: Sure, but you ought to explain what you fixed and why this works.

Comment: great!, this code works great, except the final value (FIELD20) is NaN instead of the real number. I assume the text value is not being converted correctly.

Comment: ok, searching on the internet I found this, which works. Instead of using parseInt use Math.floor   :    field20 += Math.floor(field1.value); i appreciate your help, kantholy.

Comment: explanation: 
* FIELD20/40/50 was not initialized causing problems with incrementing the value
* "document.getElementById" was missing on field1/2/3

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is best done via 'data binding'. Check out this basic example here:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#a');
var output = document.querySelector('p');

function update(event) {
   output.innerHTML = input.value;
}
input.addEventListener('keydown', update);
input.addEventListener('keyup', update);
```

We listen for key up and key down events and then change our values. [Fiddle for fun.](http://jsfiddle.net/b6d9rahu/)

This can be ungainly if you have a large table because we have to bind every input to it's output. Not so with ES6! Instead we still add listeners to our inputs, but we bind them all to a single JS object. That's one event listener instead of dozens of others. We do this via [`Object.observe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe).

Check it out:

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var output = document.querySelectorAll('td');

input = Array.prototype.slice.call(input);

/*
Here you model out your "table" as a JS object
so that we can listen for changes more easily.
*/
var table = {
    a: '',
    b: ''
};

input.forEach(function addListeners(input) {
    //Closured! 
    function update(event) {
        table[input.id] = input.value
    }
    input.addEventListener('keydown', update);
    input.addEventListener('keyup', update);
});

//You'd have to make some more clever function.
function alphaToCell(alpha) {
    if (alpha === 'a') return 0;
    if (alpha === 'b') return 1;
}

/*
The cool thing here is that instead of binding each input to it's output, we just bind every input to a single model, and then that model knows how to update all the outputs.
*/
Object.observe(table, function (changes) {
    changes.forEach(function (change) {
        var index = alphaToCell(change.name);
        output[index].innerHTML = table[change.name];
    })
});
```

[Fiddle for Fun.](http://jsfiddle.net/b6d9rahu/1/)

Comment: thanks for your code/ideas. Nope, I don't want to display the data on each increment. I have 3 columns with  14 fields in each column. Everytime a user changes any of the values on the fields, I want the javascript code to recalculate the total (which is at the bottom) for each column.

Comment: I appreciate the time you have taken to show me. The thing is that the code above by kantholy works like a charm, with just a small change as mentioned on my  comments.

Comment: @user1135218, no problem as long as you're learning something. Check out my new answer though. It'll blow your mind.

Comment: your code sounds great, and will keep it in mind for future projects. I see/undestand what it does and where it could be used but it's a bit too complex for me at the moment, I am just a beginner!

Comment: Yeah, haha :D I realized after reading your question a couple times that I had gotten a *bit* excited about ES6 and wasn't really answering *your* question.